# Headers for security

Tags: security, http, header

I've been reading articles about the protection of your website and they say to place these 3 headers:

- X-Frame-Options: DENY
- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

In my website to protect it from Website attacks, but I dont know how to declare it in my header, can someone help me with this please?

Does this goes in the HTML or into the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to put them in HTML using `<meta>` tags, as JavaScript can just remove them, and (correct) browsers will ignore them.

You need to set them as HTTP response headers on the server, and this depends on your server / framework. You also don't want to do this on every page, as it's not DRY, so you want to find a centralized solution.

You could use [modsecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) with Apache httpd or nginx, or just [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

Or if you really don't want to do any sysadmin, use a service like cloudflare.

Comment: Thanks so much, still can you tell me the method to add them in the HTML?

Comment: As Neil said, you don't want to put them into the HTML. That is wrong. You want them to be HTTP headers. What web server are you using? That will effect how to implement it correctly.